# gnuplot macro expansion in bash here document when in for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, escaping, gnuplot

I am using a bash here document (the `<< EOF` construct) to pass input to a gnuplot script, as shown in the MWE below. Call it with the name of an empty file as parameter.
The script produces the error message

```
more> do for [count=0:nsteps] {;  @DOPLOT
                              ^
      line 0: invalid character @

         line 0: Unexpected }
```

My current workaround is to use eval, however, it would be nice to understand what's going on. I might need to escape the at character `@` but had no luck with google.
Interestingly, putting the macro invocation right after the open curly bracket `{` works.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
  echo "usage: $0 <input file>"
  exit
fi
inf="$1"

/usr/bin/env gnuplot << EOF

load "$inf"

set macros
DOPLOT="pause 0.25"
print "works:"
@DOPLOT
print "works:"
do for [count=0:1] { @DOPLOT
}
print "works:"
do for [count=0:1] {
  eval DOPLOT
}
print "doesn't work:"
do for [count=0:1] {
  @DOPLOT
}

EOF
```

Comment: Did you try escaping `{` with `\{`?

Comment: @anishsane Escaping this way produces an error for the backslash.

Comment: It turns out this was a bug in gnuplot, which is now fixed in the CVS for 4.7. http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1264/

Comment: Oh... I was assuming that same gnuplot code with manual entry works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a bug.
From the answer to the bug report
http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1264/

> In general input commands are assembled by reading 'enough' input to complete a command and then interpreting it. Macro substitution is done as the first step in interpretation. But in some cases, including the one you ran into, during interpretation the program discovers it has to extend the command by reading in additional lines of input. Unfortunately it was failing to re-check for macros in the new part of the extended command.